# I'm unable to create a new React application from my terminal

Tags: reactjs

Not sure what happened since I used to be able to do it seamlessly. I get this message below when trying npx create-react-app my-app

"You are running create-react-app 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.2).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App."

I uninstalled create react app globally and force cleared the cache in terminal using

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && sudo npm cache clean -f"
```

but I keep getting this message. I also restarted my computer and the terminal but I keep getting this issue.

Comment: And you installed create-react-app locally as dev dependencie?

Comment: @Jozott That did it thanks! Made a newbie mistake :/